# DOM selector in Cheerio does not working

Tags: javascript, dom, cheerio

I'm working around a selector to catch a section from Amazon.com. I've tried different selector but problem still remained.

The page that I've gone through is [this product in Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01K6PBN7C).

```
 var $ = cheerio.load(html);

 console.log($('div[id="cm-cr-dp-review-list"]').html()); // Null
 console.log($('#cm-cr-dp-review-list').html()); // Null
```

Also, the provided html value to load function is accurate.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('span[id="productTitle"]').innerHTML
$('#cm-cr-dp-review-list').innerHTML
```

Maybe `html()` is not declared on this cheerio selector!